# How can I see which apps are using my Mac's internet bandwidth?

Tags: mac, network, applications, wifi, utilities

My MacBook Air's Wi-Fi is maxed out right now for receiving.

Now I am trying once more to download the High Sierra update. But it's telling me 6 hours left and on my usual Wi-Fi connection I only achieve half the download speed and High Sierra usually tells me the whole download will take about 2 hours.

So I think something else must also be using my bandwidth.

I'm only familiar with `top` from experience using Linux in the past and this doesn't seem to tell me about network usage.

Is there something in the Mac system which can tell me which apps are using my Wi-Fi?